# Improve speed for search a word and sort by where it has appeared most often

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to perform a SQL Server database search, I have some code and I need to improve its speed.

```
SELECT 
    [Link], [Title], [Description], [Country]
FROM
    [DMaor_MyData].[dbo].[Table_Web]
WHERE 
    CONCAT([Link], [Title], [Description], [KeyWords], [H1]) LIKE '%pic%'
ORDER BY 
    (LEN(CONCAT([Link], [Title], [Description], [KeyWords], [H1]))
   - LEN(REPLACE(CONCAT([Link], [Title], [ Description],[KeyWords], [H1]), 'pic', ''))) / LEN('pic') DESC, [LINK]
    OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I was told that `CONTAINS` is much faster to use but I do not know how to sort by it.

```
SELECT 
    [Link], [Title], [Description], [Country]
FROM
    [DMaor_MyData].[dbo].[Table_Web]
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(([Link], [Title], [Description], [KeyWords], [H1]), 'pic')
```

And I also feel that the `CONTAINS` code does not return correct results because I get quite a few results (a few dozen instead of a few hundred).

How do I improve speed for this code?

Comment: Have you got full text indexing turned on?

Comment: Full-Text Search is a whole other ball of wax. Your first query is likely not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) because it's concatenating five columns before searching the result for `'%pic%'` and likely has to perform a table scan to find the results. Would it be logically equivalent for your application to search for `[Link] like '%pic%' or ... or [H1] like '%pic%'`? SQL Server would then be able to take advantage of indexes defined on the Link, Title, Description, Keywords and H1 columns.

Comment: Your `where` criteria is definitely not sargable, you are forcing SQL Server to concatenate those columns together which it must do *first* for *every* row in the table - aka a table scan. Depending on how large these columns (potentially) are you should create a computed column of them concatenated and then index *that*.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Wildcard prefix is never sargable, you would need `LIKE 'pic%'` instead